# Get Params of a QueryString and their datatypes

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sqlparameter

Let's say you have an delphi interface that has a TEdit where an user types and SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE   X.A = :A and  X.B = :B and X.C= :C
```

Is there a way to get the types of the :A,:B,:C Params? I managed to get the name of the Params. using this code

```
procedure TfrmA.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    queryInput, queryOutput , aux : string;
    pozitie : Integer;
    param : string;
    Ch,Chx : Char;
begin
    queryInput :=  TEdit.Text;
    queryOutput := StringReplace(queryInput,':','@',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    aux := Copy(queryOutput,AnsiPos('@',queryOutput),200);
    while Length(aux ) > 0 do   begin
    if   AnsiPos('@',aux ) = 0 then break;
    for Ch in aux do
    begin
      if Ch = ' ' then begin
      param := param + ' ';
      break
      end else param := param + Ch;
    end;
    ShowMessage(param);
    test := Copy(test,2,200);
    test := Copy(test,AnsiPos('@',test),200);
    end;
end;
```

Param string will containt now : `@A @B @C`

Is there anyway I can find out the datatype of the params?

Comment: you will need to inform the field and table to know the datatype

Comment: you asked a similar question recently, in this case you need the `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters` function to retrieve the datatypes.

Comment: nitpicking comment, if you are using D2009 or higher, you should get rid of `AnsiPos`and use `Pos` function instead.

Comment: @whosrdaddy that question was abount Fields, not abount Params... belive me I won't ask a question unless I tried all possible methoes I could come up with and without surfing the net for answers.

Comment: If you read the docs about `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` (answer from previous question), they also point to `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters`which is the answer in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use a Adodataset you might use this to get the needed informations.
    uses TypInfo;

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  Ads.CommandText := 'Update Adressen set geboren=:birthdate where name=:n and ID=:i';
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  for I := 0 to Ads.Parameters.Count - 1 do
      begin
         Memo1.Lines.Add(Ads.Parameters[i].Name + ' : ' + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataType), Integer(Ads.Parameters[i].DataType)) + ' : '+ IntToStr(Ads.Parameters[i].Size) )
      end;
end;
```

The Output of the example will be:

```
birthdate : ftDateTime : 16
n : ftWideString : 40
i : ftInteger : 4
```

Comment: it seems it won't see any params. procedure TfrmRapoarte.est21Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i:Integer;
 Ads : TADODataSet;
 param : string;
begin
  Ads := TADODataSet.Create(Self);
  param := 'SELECT * FROM X where A= :A and YEAR(B)=  :B and C = :C';
  Ads.CommandText := param; 
  for I := 0 to Ads.Parameters.Count - 1 do
      begin
         Memo1.Lines.Add(Ads.Parameters[i].Name + ' : ' + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataType), Integer(Ads.Parameters[i].DataType)) + ' : '+ IntToStr(Ads.Parameters[i].Size));
      end;
end;

Comment: You will have to define a connection before setting the commandtext: `Ads.Connection := AdoConnection1;`